# Use Alamofire to Set HTTP Headers and HTTP Body

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, swift2, alamofire

I have been using NSURLConnection to make requests and I would like to migrate the codes to Alamofire.

Here is my **NSURLConnection** code.

```
var requestString: NSString = "http://api.domainname.com/api/v1/auth/register";
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: requestString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)!;

var urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url);
urlRequest.setValue("\(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization");
urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept");

var httpBodyDictionary: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary();
httpBodyDictionary.setObject(self.emailTextField.text, forKey: "email");
httpBodyDictionary.setObject(self.usernameTextField.text, forKey: "username");
httpBodyDictionary.setObject(self.passwordTextField.text, forKey: "password");

urlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST";

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if(data != nil) {
          //PROCESS DATA
    }
});
```

I have however tried Alamofire but I cant make it work..

**ALAMOFIRE**

```
var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders ?? [:]
defaultHeaders["Authorization"] = "\(base64LoginString))"
defaultHeaders["Content-Type"] = "application/json)"
defaultHeaders["Accept"] = "application/json)"

let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders;

let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)


var requestString: NSString = "http://api.domainname.com/api/v1/auth/register";
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: requestString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)!;

var urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url);
urlRequest.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue;

let parameters = ["email": self.emailTextField.text,
        "username": self.usernameTextField.text,
        "password": self.passwordTextField.text]

do {
        urlRequest.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
} catch {
    // No-op
}

Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (urlRequest, urlResponse, result) -> Void in
        print(urlResponse);        
    //print(result);
})
```

Could anyone please point to the right direction please? I have spent the whole day trying to make it work.

Note: Using Swift 2/ XCode 7 Beta 6

**UPDATE tried Rob's suggestion but instead I get this returned, this does not happen when I use NSURLConnection**

**PRINTED RESPONSE**

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fdbc222a2b0> { URL: http://api.domainname.com/api/v1/auth/register } { status code: 422, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, proxy-revalidate";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Thu, 10 Sep 2015 14:35:13 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.8.0";
    "Set-Cookie" = "laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InZjSVwvcVd3NjR6SitZSlZNMGdXdElRPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IjJBeXdWTHRlRUNQa2RTSFBDYlU0bWlBRkF3c0pzcEx2YzQxdXk0ZnlxZ2xERUkrWmFZNlNISUlyZmpnWjZkamdxVFJXaGxOQmFtVlZZWElWdnFYdlBRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI5MWY2NjU4ODViYjhlYWM4N2YwOTg2ZTA2OWYzNmU1MmE3ZWEzN2E5ZTA5ZjA5YjMyYmExN2FmMzFhZjRiMmJhIn0%3D; expires=Thu, 10-Sep-2015 16:35:13 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} })
```

Comment: BTW, in your Alamofire attempt, you have extra `)` characters in all three headers. That's probably moot, as a more dramatic simplification is probably called for, but just a FYI.

Comment: Status code 422 means "unprocessable entity", i.e., the request was syntactically correct, but with incorrect semantics (in short, the wrong  data was in the right format). I'd suggest watching the successful `NSURLConnection` request in [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com), and then repeat it with Alamofire, and see how the two requests differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to set `Content-Type` or `Accept`. You also don't have to set the request body nor use `NSJSONSerialization` yourself. Alamofire gets you out of the weeds of constructing requests. So you might do something like:

```
let requestString = "http://api.domainname.com/api/v1/auth/register"

let parameters = [
    "email"    : emailTextField.text!,
    "username" : usernameTextField.text!,
    "password" : passwordTextField.text!
]

let headers = ["Authorization": base64LoginString]

Alamofire.request(.POST, requestString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers).responseJSON { request, response, result in
    print(response)
}
```

Or, alternatively, if you don't want to build the `base64LoginString` yourself, you might also be able to do something like:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, requestString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
    .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
    .responseJSON { request, response, result in
        print(response)
}
```

If it's still not working, I'd suggest (a) edit your question, sharing the precise error messages; and (b) observe both your old code and the new code in a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and identify how precisely the two requests differ.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Really appreciate it. It still doesn't work though.

Comment: I have edited my question with the response after I use the code you suggested. Any thoughts?